# Body-only page for a 2-page form

Tags: content

I'd like to know how does it work. I'm currently done on the questions part of the form and like to do a windows.open() function for the answers. Problem is, if I put the URL of the answer page (coming from the same site), it will still come with the header tags, footer, and the side links. I was hoping for a customized body-only page for that. Got any clue on how to?

Answer (score 1):

If your answer is a custom post type, 
then copy single.php theme file, rename it as single-answer.php

In that file, remove these function call:
get_header();
get_sidebar();
get_footer();

Comment: how can i call it to the post? say i have a submit button from the first page